# How to fix missing dependency

Tags: installation, package-management

I was trying to install ruby and was disconnected in-between, so I was unable to install all dependencies. Now I can't run ruby because of the missing dependencies. Also, I am unable to reinstall this application. Please help me to solve this issue.